# error file 'XXX' not found. the file is in the program because: Root file sprcified for compilation- NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-applications, file-not-found

I am stuck on this problem for several days already. i checked several different questions that were somewhat linked to this subject but each solution failed to fix the problem. The error list in visual studio mention this error several times with different files(file 'XXX' not found. the file is in the program because: Root file specified for compilation- in my NodeJS app, when XXX stands for the complete path of the file), however; all those files exist in the directory mentioned in the error!
[a screenshot showing both the error and the file mentioned clearly where it directs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da7JK.png)

In addition, when i try to run the application on localhost it shows this:
[screenshot of the error messages shown on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMM1m.png)
where, as you can see, it says it cannot find some files that are under node_modules folder(s)(specifically xxx/ansi_html/index.js, which i understand since it's supposed to be ansi_html_community as was automaticaly generated when i run the different npm commands but i don't know how to change it).

In the list of errors it also states problems with the automatically generated ts files(for some reason, even though i specified no typescript when i run init)

here is a link to the course on youtube which i have been following: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWKjhJtqVAbnadueQ-C5keMQQiQau_i0D

edit: So far i am at the 4th video of this course playlist. So created register and login forms as well as the backend. When i downloaded axios i received many vulnerabilities though from what i understood it has no impact on the code itself. Another point i've thought to add is that i have a strange red minus sign on the node_modules folder in the client side but the error i recieve exists both on the server and client side.

here is a link to github with my project: https://github.com/ShaniSneh/blindTypingApp

Please help! Thanks for all who reply <3
P.S.- I grouped all those errors together since they seemed connected to the same underlying problem somehow. I feel like the problem is connected to the auto-generation of the project, maybe something was not created right? However, i have tried to create a new project but the problem persists. :'(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All the code in my project is in the github link i added to my question. i understand it is an automatic comment from a bot, but in case someone else thought the same thing i responded.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error, it most likely occurred because of running the npm build or similar command at the wrong directory.

Closing down all open visual studio apps and reopening them solved the issue for me at least.

Since you have been stuck on this problem for days i assume you might have already tried this approach. Please let me know if you managed to solve this issue in any other way or if it still remains an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a typescript project =>

1. Make sure that the `outDIR` and `outRoot` in `tsconfig.json` file have both the js and ts file directories mentioned.
   For example, if your javascript file is in a folder called `dist`,
   go to `tsconfig.js`, search for `outDir` => Uncomment the code => change it to `"outDir": "./dist"`,
   and if your typescript file is in a folder called `src`,
   search for `rootDir` => Uncomment the code => change it to `"rootDir": "./src"`,
2. Run the file just using `tsc` command, don't run using `tsc index.ts`.